# Жизненный цикл фрагментов

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема, которая касается жизненного цикла фрагмента.

Интерфейс:

[image]

Все ***Tabs*** создаются сразу при запуске программы и остаются в памяти, дабы сделать приятным пролистывание между ними.

**Проблема:**
При открытии вкладки *"Calculations"* хочу, чтобы выполнялось определенное действие. Проанализировав документацию, понял, что мне нужно будет использовать метод ***onStart()***. Я так и сделал, но в итоге получилось так, что данное действие выполнялось тогда, когда открывается вкладка *"Products"*. В чем может быть проблема? **Почему метод onStart(), который должен выполнятся, когда фрагмент стает видимый для пользователя, выполняется раньше?**

***MainActivity, где происходит создание Tabs***

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });


    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

***Вот FragmentPagerAdapter:***

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new DiaryFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ProductsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new CalculationsFragment();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

***Вот фрагмент Calculations:***

```
public class CalculationsFragment extends Fragment {
public CalculationsFragment(){
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculations, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Это фрагмент Calculations", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onStart();
}
```

}

Comment: Размыто это все звучит. Может, предоставите код?

Comment: @smackmychi, даже не знаю, какой фрагмент кода вам показать. Прикрепил весь onCreate() и FragmentPagerAdapter и CalculationsFragment

Comment: Скорее, нужно тот функционал, который вынесли в onStart(), вынести в отдельную функцию и вызывать в onTabSelected(n);

Comment: Советую на TabHost повесть Listener, который срабатывает при смене таба. И уже там в обработчике вызывать метод нужного фрагмента.

Comment: @Ингвар у `FragmentPagerAdapter` логика такова, что при создание текущего фрагмента, он в фоне, создает следующий за ним и хранит предыдущий фрагменты. Если замените на `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, то он уже будет создавать каждый фрагмент при его открытии. Но лучше сделайте так, как посоветовал @Suvitruf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за комментарии. Они помогли в решении проблемы. (Правда, в моем случае нужно вещать Listener на ViewPager)

[[[[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)

> Советую на TabHost повесть Listener, который срабатывает при смене таба. И уже там в обработчике вызывать метод нужного фрагмента.

[[@monomi](/users/4375/monomi)](/users/4375/monomi)

> у FragmentPagerAdapter логика такова, что при создание текущего фрагмента, он в фоне, создает следующий за ним и хранит предыдущий фрагменты. Если замените на FragmentStatePagerAdapter, то он уже будет создавать каждый фрагмент при его открытии. Но лучше сделайте так, как посоветовал [[[[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf).

[[@Lucky_spirit](/users/1012/lucky_spirit)](/users/1012/lucky_spirit)

> Скорее, нужно тот функционал, который вынесли в onStart(), вынести в отдельную функцию и вызывать в onTabSelected(n);

Comment: @Ингвар, обидно, но я как раз перед @Suvitruf посоветовал тебе то же. В listener'е, который тебе посоветовали, как раз метод onTabSelected().

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, извини, сейчас исправим :)